# SCNLookAtConstraint causing zoom past 3D model

Tags: swift3, scenekit

```
UPDATE:
```

After further testing and evaluation it seems that the SCNLookAtConstraint is causing the issue. Basically because it removes the 2 finger Pan Gesture it is causing some weird behavior with the pinch and scroll gesture. Does anyone have a good idea how to fix this?

```
override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) { 
  let quaternion = sceneView.pointOfView?.orientation
  let position = sceneView?.pointOfView?.position
  print("Orientation: ((quaternion?.x),(quaternion?.y),(quaternion?.z),(quaternion?.w)) Position: ((position?.x),(position?.y),(position?.z)") 
}
```

but this just prints out the same values now matter the 2 finger zoom pressed.

```
func setupScene() {
    let scene = SCNScene()
    self.sceneView.scene = scene

    let camera = SCNCamera()
    let cameraNode = SCNNode()
    cameraNode.camera = camera
    cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: -1.0, y: 0.0, z: -1.0)
    cameraNode.boundingBox.max = SCNVector3(x: 2, y: 2, z: 2)
    cameraNode.boundingBox.min = SCNVector3(x: 0.1, y: 0.1, z: 0.1)

    let centerNode = SCNNode()
    centerNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0)

    let light = SCNLight()
    let lightNode = SCNNode()
    light.type = .ambient
    light.color = UIColor.white
    lightNode.light = light

    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(centerNode)
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(lightNode)

    cameraNode.constraints = [SCNLookAtConstraint(target: centerNode)]
    sceneView.pointOfView = cameraNode

}
```

Comment: How are you zooming the camera? I can't see anywhere in your code that moves the camera.

Comment: Currently using the default behavior Allow camera control. It handles the gestures for me, but when using 1 finger rotation and using the 2 finger pinch gesture it is allowing my objects to zoom down to the point that it is disappearing from the view.